# How to disable a user's ability to select text in a UITextField or UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios12

How do I disable text highlighting in a `UITextField` or `UITextView`? I come from a web development background and I know it can be achieved in CSS using the following:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Is this possible in iOS?

Comment: You can make select property of textview to false.

Comment: Please add some more information what you want to achieve will clear your question and get more help from SO group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way is to set `.isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on your `UITextView` or `UITextField`